# How to force visual studion to ignore all other breakpoints except one

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

As title, How to force visual studio to ignore all other breakpoints except one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the `Debug Menu` click `Disable All Breakpoints`, then right click the Break Point in question and click `Enable Break Point`.

Answer (score 1):

With breakpoints window (Debug | Windows | Breakpoints) having focus select all (control-a), control-click the break point you want to keep (to unselect) and untick one of the selected breakpoints. All the selected breakpoints will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Astander's answer, you can bring up the debug window (<kbd>Ctrl D+B</kbd>), and it has an option there to *Enable or disable all breakpoints matching the current Search*, with the Search box just along from it. Very nifty.

Answer (score -1):

Try [exporting all your breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293657.aspx) then choose Delete All Breakpoints from the Debug menu.

you can then re-add your breakpoint and import your old ones when you're ready.